# Unable to obtain proper Transponse of data using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[This is my Raw Data screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVkcg.png)

[I want to Transpose my Data as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mdTK.png)

I tried to transpose using :

```
DataT = pd.melt(Data, id_vars=['Date'],var_name='indicator', value_name='Value')
```

I want to transpose the data using pandas
....columns of data are : Date , Unnamed: 1 , Unnamed: 2, Unnamed: 3, Unnamed: , Unnamed: 8.

Comment: Don't share your data as an image. Paste your data here

Comment: @Junkrat My data is converted to screenshot format when i tried to paste... i am unable to paste my data..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure where the date, `1998-12-30 00:00`, came from since it wasn't in your first link so I've appended it to the column of dates before inserting it into the transposed `DataFrame`.  I also wasn't sure what you wanted to name the remaining columns.  You wanted to keep the `Date` column as it is while transposing the others, which may be done like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "Date": ["", "", "", "1998-12-02 00:00", "1998-12-09 00:00", "1998-12-16 00:00", "1998-12-23 00:00"],
    "Unnamed: 1": ["KN.A24", "KN.M6", "index, 1976 = 100", "142", "126", "126", "144"],
    "Unnamed: 2": ["KN.A24", "KN.M9", "%, avg index", "110.35", "254", "412.36", "134.5"],
    "Unnamed: 3": ["KN.A24", "KN.M10", "%, avg index", "211.5", "185.25", "172", "177.5"],
    "Unnamed: 7": ["KN.A24", "KN.M12", "%, change", "38.73517787", "60.51502146", "75.11312217", "82.77511962"],
    "Unnamed: 8": ["KN.A24", "KN.M11", "%, change", "89.9864682", "101.7985612", "112.2486289", "115.2112676"],
})

df = data.iloc[:, 1:].T.rename(columns={0: "Indicator", 1: "Measure", 2: "Unit", 3: "Value"}).reset_index(drop=True)
df.insert(0, "Date", data["Date"].append(pd.Series(["1998-12-30 00:00"])).iloc[3:].reset_index(drop=True))
print(df.to_string(index=False))

#             Date Indicator Measure               Unit        Value            4            5            6
# 1998-12-02 00:00    KN.A24   KN.M6  index, 1976 = 100          142          126          126          144
# 1998-12-09 00:00    KN.A24   KN.M9       %, avg index       110.35          254       412.36        134.5
# 1998-12-16 00:00    KN.A24  KN.M10       %, avg index        211.5       185.25          172        177.5
# 1998-12-23 00:00    KN.A24  KN.M12          %, change  38.73517787  60.51502146  75.11312217  82.77511962
# 1998-12-30 00:00    KN.A24  KN.M11          %, change   89.9864682  101.7985612  112.2486289  115.2112676
```

Comment: I want all the value in one column  . What can i do for that? Any suggestion @Dylon

Comment: Just use either `df.column_name` or `df["column_name"]`, where `df` is your `DataFrame`.  Is that what you're asking?